# Access local Javascript file from a local HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

There are many questions similar to this but none of them have been able to help me.

I am new to HTML and JS development.  I have a simple HTML file that is trying to access a simple Javascript file.

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("In HTML")

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src=./asdf.js></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map3d" style="height:400px;width:600px;border:1px solid red"></div>
</body>
```

The Javascript file is named asdf and exists in the same location as the HTML.  I have tried the full file path, just the name "asdf.js" and several other options I can't recall.

My .js file reads thusly:

```
<script>
document.write("In JS")
</script>
```

The "In JS" doesn't appear.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External scripts do not require `<script>` and `</script>`. Write external scripts *as if you were writing in between* the tags.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  But there is apparently still another problem because "In JS" still doesn't display.

Comment: It actually might be displaying.  You are executing your JavaScript in the `<head>` block and not the `<body>`

Comment: @KyleWright you can check for errors using the console (F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+I in most browsers)

Comment: Adding it to the <body> didn't seem to help.  Pressing F12 suggested to me that there were no errors.

Comment: Never mind, you guys steered me right.  When I made your changes I also changed something else, which turned out to be a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

In your JS file remove the `<script>` and `</script>` tags. They are for using JavaScript embedded within HTML, not for external file.